# How exactly does the a2billing softswitch generate call records?

Tags: asterisk

I just installed Asterisk 11 and a2billing 2.01.  I followed instructions for the a2billing installation and everything was OK. It works.

But... There are no call traces being recorded into the a2billing database!!!
As I understand it, it uses the "cc_call" table for call recording - but this table is empty!

I need all calls recorded, not only answered. I'm making calls via AGI using their PHP scripts. The following is my dial plan:

```
;For standard inbound call
[a2billing]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(A2Billing Start)
exten => _X.,n,Agi(/usr/share/a2billing/AGI/a2billing.php,1)
exten => h,1,Hangup
```

This starts the IVR which tells me my account balance (how much money I have left), and then asks me to choose a number to dial.

I have a trunk for the call, created as has been recommended. After the call my balance is decreased; i.e., the call has been charged. But I cannot see any call records inserted into the database.

My questions are: How exactly does a2billing generate CDR's? What do I need to do to have the calls recorded?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by arheops, A2billing store CDRs in it's own Mysql Database, within a table called cc_call, the table is very similar to the Asterisk CDR table but contains extra fields to store the buy/sell rates, cost of calls and relation to the rate/callplan tables.

When you send a call to the AGI, A2Billing will try first to authenticate the users, if it succeed then the outbound call will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

A2Billing create cdrs via by agi script. You can got it in cc_call table.

For record calls you have change agi-confX and set key for recording(in config section of web)